# ng-bootstrap popover over svg element

Tags: svg, popover, ng-bootstrap

I am using [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) and I want to add a popover or tooltip over a svg elemet. I need this popover to contain a button and some texts.

What I have tried is this:

```
<ng-template #popContent>Book this seat <button>Book</button></ng-template>

<svg:circle [attr.id]="seat.id" class="seat tooltips" [attr.cx]="seat.x" [attr.cy]="seat.y" r="4" style="fill: rgb(206, 206, 206);" [ngbPopover]="popContent"></svg:circle>
```

I also have the library imported:

```
import { PopoverModule } from "../../../../node_modules/ngx-popover";
```

And I am running bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6.

It does not show up, because the generated popover is being placed inside the svg and the browser can not render it that way. Is there some possible workaround, some way I could show these popovers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `container` option as described in the [API documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api):

> A selector specifying the element the popover should be appended to. Currently only supports "body".

By using `container="body"` you can have a popover window added as a child of the `<body>` element (instead of being a sibling of the SVG's circle element):

```
<ng-template #popContent>Book this seat <button>Book</button></ng-template>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <svg:circle [attr.id]="seat.id" [attr.cx]="seat.x" [attr.cy]="seat.y" r="4" style="fill: rgb(206, 0, 0);" [ngbPopover]="popContent" container="body"></svg:circle>
</svg>
```

Here is a working plunker demonstrating this: http://plnkr.co/edit/lVYsY3LDVX9WGZhbMBMu?p=preview

Please also note that the **proper import** is `import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';` - check the linked plunker for the complete example.

Comment: Sorry I answered my question and did not refresh to see you also answered in the meanwhile, thanks for the solution and working demo.

I have now another issue, I would like to have the popover open on mouse over the circle and I would like to close it after the mouse leaves the popover(not the circle), because i would like it to be interactive. `triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"` does not work like this, it closes right after the mouse leaves the circle. I started to implement a complex manual trigger, but is there an easier way?

Comment: @padr "manual" triggers are the way to go in the case, IMO. I don't think it is complex to implement, see: http://plnkr.co/edit/9FbFjkLf4XeicvSA8YdZ?p=preview

Comment: I cant make it work correctly. I would need something like a delay. I dont want the popover to be displayed when I go off the circle but not touch the popup. But, again, I want to have enought time to move over from the circle to the popup if I want.

Comment: it works for me: `<path  placement="top" container="body" [ngbPopover]="popContent" [popoverTitle]="popTitle" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" class=house" id="h1" style="fill:#FFFFFF;/>`

Answer (score 2):

I made it work:

There is an option called container which specify the place where the popover is appended.

```
container="body"
```

Only "body" is supported currently.